# how can you bypass the filter chain in magnolia cms?

Tags: java, spring, content-management-system, servlet-filters, magnolia

How can I bypass all the filter chain?

I'd like that the url's that start with `/web/` to be bypassed so that the spring dispatcher can receive them.

Thanks :)

Comment: related: http://forum.magnolia-cms.com/forum/thread.html?threadId=d7d48efd-87ca-4423-bd7b-4d5a9379f531

Answer (score 2):

In Magnolia, you can configure bypasses under each filter node in /server/filters ... or directly under that node to bypass the complete chain. 
You can also simply change the mapping in your web.xml

Comment: In my web.xml i've configured the servlet for blossom (magnolia module). I've created a custom module where i'm trying to load spring inside magnolia. In this module descriptor i've declared it's servlet for spring. I'd like inside the magnolia filter chain to add a bypass as you said for the complete chain so that when the url starts with /web to direct the request to the spring servlet instead of the blossom one. The only problem is that I don't really know how to do that.. is this approach ok? thanks :)

Comment: The BlossomDispatcherServlet is invoked as part of Magnolia rendering pages, there's no involvement of the servlet container here. The controllers are not reachable from the outside world. So you don't need to excluded their paths. If your intention is to add a controller that _should_ be accessible from the outside world (not annotated with @Template or @Paragraph) then i would recommend you add a DispatcherServlet to your modules xml file. You won't need to excluded that either as its invoked from within the filter chain.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a uri from being processed by the Magnolia filter chain add a mapping to /server/webContainerResources/mappings in Configuration.

Another option is to add an exclude on the whole filter chain. This means that the filter chain is completely bypassed, whereas adding a WebContainerResource mapping means that some filters are applied. For instance the filter that sets up the Magnolia context.

For more details see [Request processing and filters](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/technical-guide/request-processing-and-filters.html) in the Technical Guide.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of, is to directly invoke the dispatcher servlet `service(..)` method from your filter. How to obtain the dispatcher servler - it should be registered as a spring bean, so I guess you can take it from the context with `WebApplicationContextUtils`

But that's ugly. You should better configure your filter mapping urls. And in fact, what would be the reason of some filter not continuing to the dispatcher servlet?